# Magento 2 - Estimate shipping costs block on homepage

Tags: magento2, layout, shipping

I am trying to include the Estimate shipping costs block on my homepage.

[image]

In my layout file (cms_index_index.xml) I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/shipping.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But this only includes the first line of text then nothing else. There are no errors in the console.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I just wasn't including enough layout information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <container name="postcode.popup" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="postcode-popup" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/shipping.phtml" after="checkout.cart.summary.title">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--Step configuration components-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">summary-block-config</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">block-summary.block-shipping.address-fieldsets</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-fieldsets</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.country_id</item>
                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                                            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                                        <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">111</item>
                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                        <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/cart/totals/shipping</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>

                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The Estimate shipping and Tax block now appears correctly on the homepage.